# Getting error Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory while accessing web site

Tags: content-delivery

When we are accessing the web sites, frequently getting the below error. But as work around once recycling the application pool the web site running fine. Could you please help me to get the root cause of the issue.

in addition to the above, please be informed that sites were working fine till few days before.

Thanks in advance.
Regards

---

Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory

Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 21/08/2015 14:52:29 
Event time (UTC): 21/08/2015 13:52:29 
Event ID: 3616cf8dc6ce4cb5b8f18c190d30972f 
Event sequence: 4 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/35/ROOT-168-130846387440929386 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: \UNC PATH\Repository\no\ 
    Machine name: XXXXXXXX

Process information: 
    Process ID: 3860 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: XXXX\Ptridionweb

Exception information: 
    Exception type: Throwable 
    Exception message: 
  java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError

Some configured classpath roots cannot be found

================================================

```
ClassPath           : \\UNC PATH\Repository\eu\bin\bin
ClassPath           : \\UNC PATH\Repository\int\bin\bin
ClassPath           : \\UNC PATH\Repository\nl\bin\bin
ClassPath           : \\UNC PATH\Repository\no\bin\bin
```

============================================================
Some Java classes or interfaces could not be found or loaded

The most typical reasons for this problem are:

- you forgot to configure a classpath
- a jarfile, zipfile, or directory is missing from your
  classpath
- you have a typo in one of your classpath entries
- a jarfile required by one of your classes is missing from
  your classpath
- a jarfile on your classpath is out-of-date and does not
  contain some new classes

============================================================

com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPARatingDAO
  com.tridion.preview.web.util.HandleSessionContentUtil
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.WebserviceExtensionType
  com.tridion.validation.adapter.ContentValidatorSpringAdapter
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.InvalidTokenException
  com.tridion.validation.ValidationFacade
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenProcessor
  com.tridion.web.asp.ASPAdmin
  com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Rating
  com.tridion.web.jsp.ResponseWrapper
  com.tridion.validation.ValidationException
  com.tridion.webservices.linking.LinkingService
  com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.BinaryLinkingAdaptor
  com.tridion.siteedit.preview.PreviewClaimStoreProvider
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataRequestContext
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.UGCValidationFacade
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler
  com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter
  com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.ComponentLinkingAdaptor
  com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Comment
  com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.PageLinkingAdaptor
  com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.DynamicComponentLinkingAdaptor
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPAUserDAO
  com.tridion.validation.adapter.ErrorsImp$Error
  com.tridion.webservices.security.validator.OAuth2RequestValidator
  com.tridion.ugc.validation.DoubleCommentingValidator
  com.tridion.validation.adapter.ErrorsImp
  com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPXSLTProcessor
  com.tridion.ugc.validation.DoubleRatingValidator
  com.tridion.preview.web.BinaryContentHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataBatchResponse
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessToken
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPACommentDAO
  com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPProcessor
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataResponse
  com.tridion.util.HttpStatusCodes
  com.tridion.ugc.Status
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.persistence.JPAItemStatsDAO
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataMediaType
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.UGCConfigurationLoader
  com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationHelper
  com.tridion.web.Admin
  com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.User
  com.tridion.preview.web.PageHandler
  [Lcom.tridion.webservices.extension.WebserviceExtensionType;
  com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2ResponseMessage
  com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.ItemStats
  com.tridion.preview.web.util.AmbientDataUtil
  com.tridion.util.ServiceExtensionException
  [Lcom.tridion.ugc.Status;
  [Lcom.tridion.util.HttpStatusCodes;
  com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor
  com.tridion.ugc.taglib.model.Item
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.RatingDAO
  com.tridion.validation.ContentValidator
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataServiceOperation
  com.tridion.validation.Errors
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.UserDAO
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.WebserviceExtension
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataWritableEntryService
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataResourceBundleRegistrationService
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.CommentDAO
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataWritableStreamEntryService
  com.tridion.storage.ugc.dao.ItemStatsDAO

]]>
  (ComponentPresentationFactory.java:88)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args)
   at Com.Tridion.Dcp.ComponentPresentationFactory..ctor(String itemURI)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.ComponentPresentationFactory..ctor(String itemUri)
   at Ricoh.Navigation.NavigationDisplayHelper.initialise(String currentPath, String publicationUri, String componentId)
   at Ricoh.Navigation.NavigationDisplayHelper.GetAccessControls(String currentPath, String publicationUri, String primaryNavComponentId)
   at ASP.AccessControl.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)]]>

Comment: the trace seems to show UGC calls, do you have it enabled and if so, are the ugc jars also present in the lib folder?

Comment: Hi Roli, thanks for your reply. But we have not enabled UGC.

Answer (score 2):

Some tips:

-Double check your cd_licenses.xml file in order to ensure the expiration date is correct.

-Have you updated recently your Java version? May be rolling back the java version could help

Comment: Thanks Julian for your reply. I have checked both and they are correct. It is not that we are getting the error every time rather application throwing the error sometimes and once we recycle the application pool it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

From your provided details in questions and other comments. i think it could be of following reasons.

- One of the JAR required by your particular section of code is missing
  or  32/64 bit issue.
- check [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20151031093958/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/p/unblockingdownloadedfile.aspx) also for your jar and dlls
- check for UGC tag in your configs. either its enabled mistakenly and jar is missing (as mentioned by Roli)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information I can only guess; I have seen these kinds of issues when you have **too many** jars in your lib folder. You need to remove the UGC jars (and any other that you don't need) from the lib folder and verify that the storage (and/or deployer) configuration doesn't contain any references to UGC tag handlers and/or storage bundles.

The Tridion installation sources contain subfolders per role. For any web application you need to copy only the jars for the roles the web application needs to fulfill (and not all jars from all roles).

Lastly; I would always recommend against running websites via UNC paths as I've seen many issues on sites setup that way that 'normal' sites don't have (license validation errors when everything is in the right place, things not being able to load, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it was because of the jets3t.properties configuration was pointing to the wrong proxy.

```
#JetS3t properties
httpclient.proxy-autodetect=false
httpclient.proxy-host=proxy.domain.com
httpclient.proxy-port=3128
```